# Why are certain aspects of my Rails app throwing an exception publicly when I deploy to Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment, heroku

I am working my way through [Michael Hartl's Ruby on Rails Tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/) (on Mac OSX 10.7.2/Ruby 1.9.2/Rails 3.1.1) and just finished Chapter 2, which concludes with deploying a  demo twitter app to Heroku.

Everything appears to be working properly when I run the app locally AND I was able to successfully deploy the app to Heroku in some capacity because it is available here: http://rich-twitter-baby.heroku.com/

However, what I can't figure out is why the /users and /microposts pages aren't showing up publicly (with lists of users and microposts respectively) as they do locally. I migrated my database to Heroku and pushed the info up there and everything seemed to work properly, but I get [this error message](http://rich-twitter-baby.heroku.com/users) when I try to view the pages publicly.

I've tried running "heroku console" but get this error:

```
Unable to attach to a dyno to open a console session.
Your application may have crashed.
Check the output of "heroku ps" and "heroku logs" for more information.
```

And the logs say [error H13](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes#h13__connection_closed_without_response), while the ps looks like this:

```
Process       State               Command
------------  ------------------  ------------------------------
web.1         idle for 1h         thin -p $PORT -e $RACK_ENV -R $HER..
```

Let me know if anyone has any ideas or if more info would help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I would contact Heroku support on this.  Dynos can crash and become 'zombiefied' which means they just sit there idle.

Normally these will clear themselves out within a few hours, but it shouldn't happen that often if at all.

Doing a new deploy will also normally restart everything back to clean.

If it's consistently happening, have you tried spinning up the application locally in production mode to try and reproduce the problem

```
rails server -e production
```

, or adding something like the Airbrake add-on to your app to capture the error.

Comment: got it. will look into things with heroku support and consider the alternatives you suggested as well. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check your log using

```
$> heroku logs
```

At the command line of your development system that you used to push to heroku.

Post the log here if you can't figure it out from that.

Answer (score 0):

I contacted Heroku Support about this issue and it turns out that the answer had to do with which stack my app was being deployed to. I did their workaround and everything is now up and running. Here's the full info from them:

> It looks like the problem is that you're using Rails 3.1 and our Bamboo stack; we have full >asset pipeline support on our Cedar stack[1]. Since this is just a demo app, an easy >workaround is to precompile locally and commit the files:

```
rake assets:precompile 
git add -A 
git commit -m "precompiling assets" 
git push heroku master
```

> To get full asset pipeline support, you need to create your app on the Cedar stack and then >repeat the process you did to get your Bamboo app to work.
>
> [1]: http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails31_heroku_cedar